# HTML does not find stylesheet info

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm building a website with  elements and want to style my elements with a CSS stylesheet. Both the css- and html files are in the same folder. Changes in my css however do not result in changes in my website. I have the following code (I blanked out some text)`enter code here`:

```css
div.contact {
  top: 70px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <br>
  <p> Voor andere vragen kan u ons contacteren op: </p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <a href="mailto: XXX">  XXX  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The styles in your snippet are being applied fine. Have you checked in your browsers developer tools to see if the file is being loaded or if the styles are applied? This could also be a browser caching issue which could be easily resolved by pressing ctrl + f5

Comment: its working.. just write background-color:red; to check

Comment: If this is really how your website is laid out, I would highly recommend using CSS rather than multiple `<br>` tags to pad out your content.

Answer (score 1):

your CSS should be

```
.contact {
   position: absolute;
   top: 70px;
   left: 300px;
   width: 50%;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it didn't help. I tried both adding position: absolute; and padding top: / margin top:.

Comment: Hey, I tried this but it is working, I don't know that you are doing wrong. Please see the below code.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>contact</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="contact" >
    <br>
    <p > Voor andere vragen kan u ons contacteren op: </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="mailto: XXX">  XXX  </a>
    </p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

And style.css:

```
div.contact {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    }
```

please be specific if wrong.

Comment: @havaey Just tried this, it works. Can you please edit your answer and show me how you're importing your stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm changing my answer so you may understand better,
if you want top play with position (top/right/bottom/left) you have to specify:

```
position:relative;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
```

depending on your needs,

I don't know if you posted your full code, but you should try this code instead:

```css
.contact{
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 50%;
}

.contact2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 50%;
}

.contact3{
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-left: 300px;
    width: 50%;
}

.contact4{
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contact" >
        <br>
        <p > Voor andere vragen kan u ons contacteren op: </p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    
        <a href="mailto: XXX">  XXX  </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can either switch your class to

```
contact2, contact3, or contact4 to try it out,
```

It should be fine

Comment: relative works too!

Comment: I tried and it doesn't if you dont specify it  :o I'll change my answer then

Comment: I have updated my answer so you may undersdant better

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your stylesheet is loaded in the HTML. In order to do this, add the following inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

That is, if your CSS-file is called `style.css`. Otherwise, just change the name.